# How to send object from front end to back end?

Tags: reactjs

[I tried to send the form with axios but it doesn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mggWa.png)

[1.action url in the form tag doesn't work (without axios)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnGAO.png)
2.I made a onSubmitHandler to use axios but, there is only one space in the form onSubmit tag.
3.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the method and action from your form, it's not necessary
- It doesn't seem to me that you're actually calling onSubmitHandler based on the images.
- The data on your onSubmit function should have all registered fields from react-hook-form, like so `{ nickname: 'value', ... }`
- You can pass to your onSubmit function the axios call, like so:

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  const response = await axios.post('url', data);
}
```

If that doesn't work, then please give more information about what would be the issue. Your question is hard to understand and might need a bit more context. Also, avoid external images and add the minimal reproducible code right on the question body.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).